# XML SOAP -> WEBSERVICE REST

Tags: java, rest, soap

Gostaria de saber se é possível enviar um xml no padrão SOAP para um "endpoint" em REST? Ou se a melhor forma seria criar o Webservice em SOAP para não misturar os protocolos?

Pergunto isso, pq temos estamos refazendo todo o backend (JEE7) para REST, porém há um "pedaço" da aplicação, em que recebemos o xml (prestação de contas) no padrão SOAP. A empresa que envia o xml para consumirmos em nossa aplicação não irá mudar o padrão de envio tão cedo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim é possível de se fazer, porém você terá que adaptar o retorno de todos os endpoints que respondam a uma requisição via SOAP.

Existe um projeto que tomei como base pra me guiar quando precisei realizar a mesma coisa em uma aplicação. O projeto pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://sourceforge.net/projects/soaprest-mocker/).

Comment: Estava dando uma olhada no projeto que vc mencionou. A adaptação do retorno de todos os endpoints que vc referiu, seria implementar uma classe no padrão REST? Ou ainda teria que ter uma classe igual ao projeto que tem o @Endpoint?

Eu não estou usando o fw Spring para implementar aqui então, me confundiu um pouco esta parte do exemplo...